# How do click a button and enable another button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter. I have a flatbutton with an image and i want to click that and enable another flatbutton with an image. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is fairly straight forward. Have you tried anything yourself? Post your best effort.
Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

have you tried IgnorePointer ?, you can set the second Button inside a IgnorePOinter, and when u click the first button u can change the ignorepointer properties to enable the second button.